# make javascript code content dropdownlist dependant

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I found this code on the internet, I'm using it to populate a textbox with autocomplete elements, the problem I have tho is that I also have a DropDownList that lets you choose between three languages, and I would like to change a parameter depending on the selected language. This is the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#<%=txtCompanyName.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Default.aspx/GetCompanyName",
                data: "{ 'pre':'" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return { value: item }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to change the "url: Default.aspx/GetCompanyName" parameter everytime I switch the language on the DropDownList. I tried a lot of things, but I think the closest was this:

```
...
if(document.getElementById('DropDownListName').value == "Company")
url: "Default.aspx/GetCompanyName",
} else {
url: "Default.aspx/IgnoreInput",
}
...
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you're trying to access an ASP.Net control and you do *not* have `ClientIDMode="static"` on it, realize that the ID will not be what you expect. To see this first-hand, Right Click the dropdown and do Inspect Element, and examine the ID. Because of this, `getElementById('DropDownListName')` may not find anything. Cite your other example, where you're using `<%=txtCompanyName.ClientID%>` to fetch the *rendered* ID. Also, is that last snippet contained within an event to capture the dropdown changing, or is it just in the middle of your code...?

Comment: Sorry, I've just seen the end of your text. I tried to use that code as an individual function, but then the autocomplete didn't load. Then I tried to implement it into the main code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets assume your dropdown has static values like this, you can fire this each time the dropdown changes:

```
    <select id="languages" onchange="OnLanguageChange(this)">
    <option value="default.aspx/GetCompanyEN">English</option>
    <option value="default.aspx/GetCompanyFR">Francais</option>
    <option value="default.aspx/GetCompanyES">Espanol</option>
  </select>
```

add your code to this function to meet your needs, so the el.value would be your url

```
 function OnLanguageChange(el) {
        alert(el.value)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, just didn't visit the page since! Tried to give you score, but I'm too underscored to score.

Comment: i think you should be able to accept the answer if indeed it worked for you. thanks.